# run rsync through execvp: StrictHostKeyChecking=no: unknown option

Tags: c++, linux, rsync, execvp

I am trying to run rsync through execvp with StrictHostKeyChecking option.
This is my code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
        char *argv[] = {"rsync",
                        "remote_user@1.2.4.5:/tmp",
                        "/home/tmp/",
                        "-e 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'",
                        0};
        execvp("rsync", argv);
}
```

I am getting this error:

*rsync: -e '-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no': unknown option
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1422) [client=3.0.6]*

I have tried another way:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
        char *argv[] = {"rsync",
                        "remote_user@1.2.4.5:/tmp",
                        "/home/tmp/",
                        "-e",
                        "'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'",
                        0};
        execvp("rsync", argv);
}
```

But now it is failing with error:

rsync: Failed to exec ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no: No such file or directory (2) rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(84) [sender=3.0.6]

Why it don't understand StrictHostKeyChecking option?

Comment: I think `execvp` is expecting this to be split into arguments like the shell would do.  So moving `-e` into its own thing is going in the right direction.  I would next try removing the single quotes around the ssh argument.  The shell would strip those too.

Answer (score 1):

`rsync` expects to receive the options first, followed by the hosts. You're doing it backwards: first you need to specify `-e` and `-o`.

You also shouldn't be single-quoting the `-o` option: that is needed when invoking it from bash, to prevent bash from interpreting the arguments and splitting them into separate `argv[]` entries. Think about it: when `bash` sees `'-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'`, it passes `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` as a single `argv[]` entry, without the single quotes (because the single quotes is your way to tell the shell that you don't want argument splitting).

Last, but not least, you should check that `execvp(3)` didn't fail.

So, this is what you need:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *argv[] = {
        "rsync",
        "-e",
        "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no",
        "remote_user@1.2.4.5:/tmp",
        "/home/tmp/",
        NULL
    };


    if (execvp("rsync", argv) < 0) {
        perror("rsync(1) error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return 0;
}
```